# Run a single foreach to get two sets of values

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
  'a' => 'va',
  'b' => 'vb',
  'c' => 'vc',
)
```

From this array, I want to get a string like this:

```
INSERT INTO Post(a, b, c) VALUES ('va', 'vb', 'vc');
```

Now, I have to run 2 `foreach` loops (one inside `Post()` to get the array keys, one inside `VALUES()` to get the array values). Is there anyway that I can get what I want with only 1 `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) twice, first on the array keys, then on the values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Post(" . 
        implode(', ', array_keys($arr)) . 
        ") VALUES ('" . 
        implode("', '", $arr) . 
        "');";
echo $sql;
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO Post(a, b, c) VALUES ('va', 'vb', 'vc');
```

If you want to use a `foreach` loop (e.g. to deal with `NULL` values in the array), you could use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Post(";
$columns = $values = '';
foreach ($arr as $column => $value) {
    $columns .= "$column, ";
    $values .= $value ? "'$value', " : "NULL, ";
}
$sql .= trim($columns, ', ') . ") VALUES (" . trim($values, ', ') . ");";
echo "$sql\n";
```

Or possibly this to avoid the use of `trim`:

```
$cols = count($arr);
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Post(";
$columns = $values = '';
for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++) {
    $key = $keys[$c];
    $columns .= $key;
    $values .= $arr[$key] ? "'{$arr[$key]}'" : "NULL";
    if ($c < $cols - 1) {
        $columns .= ', ';
        $values .= ', ';
    }
}
$sql .= "$columns) VALUES ($values);";
echo "$sql\n";
```

Note this assumes you might want to insert `NULL` to get a default value, obviously you can simply add an `if` clause to skip `NULL` values instead.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/p35cT)

Comment: I really want to find a best way to do that (for the future), this way is O(2n) right? I want to find a way that uses only O(n) in total.

Comment: And by the way, I have to run foreach to check if the value is not null

Comment: @LuuHoangBac Unless you run this code a lot of times, the difference in time will be insignificant. It will take *far* longer to actually perform the query than generate it.

Comment: @LuuHoangBac What do you want to do if the value is null?

Comment: I also write an UPDATE Statement from that array (if the value is null, I won't print out the array key and value to the UPDATE statement)

Comment: @LuuHoangBac please see my edit, it should address your comments

Comment: I got the idea, thank you. One other question: Is there any way in PHP that I can do this: `$value1 = $value2 = trim($this, ', ')` (`$this` represent `$value1` and `$value2`)

Comment: @LuuHoangBac no, `$this` can only be used in context of an object.